# Error in update attribute contain '-' in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm having trouble when update attribute contain '-' :

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
          $qustiondata = qustionmodel::find($id);
             $qustiondata->name-man = $request->get('name-man');/*problem expression is not assignable constant reference*/
             $qustiondata->type = $request->get('type');/*no problem here*/

             $qustiondata->save();/*will happen problem if write $qustiondata['name-man'] */
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work this way, If you have keys with the dash `-` you should use  brackets `[]` or braces `{}` instead :

```
$qustiondata["name-man"] = $request->get('name-man');
//Or
$qustiondata->{"name-man"} = $request->get('name-man');
```

Comment: this make $qustiondata array,will make anther error when writ $qustiondata->save();

Comment: @KhalidHasan, unless that `find` call is returning `null` (which means a bad `id`) the code above will set the `name-man` attribute on the model instance as Model implements `ArrayAccess` ... `$qs = new qustionmodel; $qs['name-man'] = $request->input('name-man');`